When refreshing token, getting 'client_invalid', even though I used the same client to get the refresh token
To be clear, I can get access and refresh tokens without a problem. I can even POST & GET while my original Access Token is active and hasn't expired. But when I try to refresh my token following this: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-OAUTH-TOKEN-GENERATION-USING-SNOWFLAKE-CUSTOM-OAUTH
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
    --user "zj3myCplUa41CjG4o+QD6cYEPW4=:Y2XRIxxxxxxx2myJXgYoqsxSp8=" \
    --data-urlencode "grant_type=refresh_token" \
    --data-urlencode "refresh_token=ver:2-hint:8001830917-did:1014-ETMsDgAAAYclXmkuAxx---xxPSGXxUdaJKZlySzA==" \
    --data-urlencode "redirect_uri=https://localhost.com"

With my valid Client ID and Client Secret that I used initially when getting the access token and refresh token, I now am getting this error.
{
  "data" : null,
  "error" : "invalid_client",
  "code" : null,
  "message" : "This is an invalid client.",
  "success" : false,
  "headers" : null
}

How could I use the client ID and client secret without a problem to get the tokens in the first place, but when I try to refresh the token, it says invalid_client?
Either way, I am looking for any insight or help as I am generally newer to Snowflake and have probably spent too much time on this. I might be missing something super basic.
--
Also, as some additional info, that documentation shows them sending over the ver: 1-hint:... token, which for me is the Access token, whereas the Refresh token I receive is ver: 2-hint:.... Should I be sending my original expired access token? Or is this an oversight in the document?

I think the "user" which is the client_id in this case should be encoded while getting the access token renewed.
This document explains the details / steps for the same - https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Generate-renewed-access-token-using-Refresh-Token-in-OAuth2
